# Passing Object Using Expo Router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I need to pass an object from one screen to another using `expo-router`

I have a screen that shows a FlatList with items and a detail screen that would show more information about the item. The additional information is within the item object so another API call is not necessary.

The item model is as such:

```
{
  id: "123",
  title: "Some Title",
  imageURL: "https://...",
  ...other: "some other data"
}
```

using expo-router I believe I need to provide URL params, however, with the data that I have including an image URL it's not practical.

How do I go about just passing the object without URL parameters

Currently I get the item in a function as below;

```
const getDetails = (item) => {
    router.push({ pathname: `/details/${item.id}`, params: { item } });
};
```

How do I get this out in the second screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've struggled with this myself too, and I haven't found any satisfactory solution. In your case you could slightly change the code that pushes the next screen:

```
router.push({ pathname: `/details/${item.id}`, params: item }); // Remove the braces in params
```

Then, following your example in the [id].tsx file you would have something like this:

```
export default function ItemDetail() {
  const item = useLocalSearchParams();

  ...

}
```

The `item` object will have all the fields of the `params` parameter, plus the one of the route (e.g if the route is `/{id}`) it will have the id field as well.
Unfortunately, since expo will pass every field as a query parameter in the URL, it is limited:

- You wont be able to pass nested objects (fields in Item can't be objects)
- You won't be able to pass objects whose fields contain URLs (expo will complain about the format of the route).
- Field types like dates will be sent as strings.

It's not the best solution. What I've also thought about is just passing the id in the route and inside the component query the object from some memory cache.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern as written in [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#what-should-be-in-params). @Ammar Faris suggestion about storing it in global state is more correct.

Comment: The docs you pointed out are about React-Navigation, the question is about Expo-Router, you can read the [docs](https://expo.github.io/router/docs/migration/react-navigation/params/). I answered within the constraints of the question. I also mentioned that it's not the optimal solution and a memory store could be used. @Ammar Faris is not introducing anything new to this topic.

Answer (score 8):

According to the react-navigation official docs:

We should store them **in a global store** instead of the navigation state.

[Mentioned here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#what-should-be-in-params)

The downsides of passing the object in the navigation state is also mentioned in the link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current one (by Marcel) is promoting anti-patterns that might cause bugs later.